# Item to Display for Picker don't show up on load

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

This is Xamarin Forms app. I'm using Fresh MVVM. I have Modification Page, where i can change boolean value with picker (true, false, null).
I have list of boolean values (for each picker - one value and in ViewModel list filled from DB).Bool converts (using converter) to object with two values: Text(string) and Value(bool?) which is class - CheckListValue written below.

The logic - i'm putting some values with picker, saving it to DB and after i can modify it, so on load, i should see chosen value. But picker field - empty.
[Here is result, what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzBi3.png). I should see Binded Item in ItemDisplayBinding, and its Text (Negative, Positive or Empty).

I thought that the problem in Binding, but it seems okay.

```
<Picker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CheckListValueList,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}" SelectedItem="{Binding CheckListProperties.SomeBooleanValue, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToCheckListConverter}}"/>
```

here is CheckListValue

```
public static CheckListValue Positive=> new CheckListValue
{
    Text = "Positive",
    Value = true
};
public static CheckListValue Negative=> new CheckListValue
{
    Text = "Negative",
    Value = false
};
public static CheckListValue Empty=> new CheckListValue
{
   Text = "Empty",
   Value = null
};
public static List<CheckListValue> All => new List<CheckListValue>
{
    Positive, Negative, Empty
};

}
public class CheckListValue
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool? Value { get; set; }
}
```

And converter:

```
public class BoolNullableToCheckListValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var boolValue = value as bool?;
        if (!boolValue.HasValue)
            return CheckListValues.Empty;

        return boolValue.Value ? CheckListValues.Positive : CheckListValues.Negative;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var checkListValue = value as CheckListValue;

        return checkListValue?.Value;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    public List<CheckListValue> CheckListValueList => CheckListValues.All;
    public CheckListProperties CheckListProperties { get; set; }

    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        //Here CheckListProperties takes from DB on every load of Page
    }

    public class CheckListProperties
    {    
    public bool? PickerBool1 { get; set; }
    public bool? PickerBool2 { get; set; }
    public bool? PickerBool3 { get; set; }
    }
```

When i'm choosing from picker it works good, changes bool correctly and displays text, but this is modification page and on load, i should see already chosen before values, but its not. Its empty.

Do you know why it could be? Because i have no idea.

Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: I'm sorry I dont really understand what's your prob ? When you leave page and come back again, you want the picker to still display what you chose before ? For what I can see for now, you should use ObservableCollection<CheckListValue> if you want binding and property changes to work properly instead of List<> in your ViewModel

Comment: @Umar3x, sorry, i'm not very good in explanation. I just want to display correctly ItemDisplayBinding, because for now its empty on load. All data taken from DB - correct.

Comment: Ok... and if you click on the picker its not empt, you got data in it, right ? So what you want is just when page loads picker having one selected item at least. How are you setting the CheckListProperties object in the Init function and how does this object look like ?

Comment: @Umar3x, yes, correct, i have list of item and if choose - it works good. How i set data - this is works throw WebAPI, i calls method, which returns object, which have a lot of bool properties. I will add it to question, how it look like.

Comment: But the CheckListProperties is another object ? Cause you are binding ItemSource to a List of CheckListValue and then binding the SelectedItem to CheckListProperties.SomeBooleanValue ... I don't get it. Your selectedItem should be same type as ItemsSource objects which is CheckListValue. And you should try to use ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: @Umar3x, yes, correct. For this i using Converter, which converts bool to CheckListValue. I've wrote code of this converter in question above. CheckListProperties - this is just container for passing bools, because there are a lot of bool values, actually.

Comment: Oh yes sorry did not check the converter ... And what about property changes. I don't see any implementation on your ViewModel ? When CheckListProperties changes, where do you raise the OnPropertyChanged ?

Comment: @Umar3x, Xamarin Forms doing it instead of me, as you can see, there are property Binding with Mode=TwoWay, so i don't need to raise it by myself. Actually it works for other controls. The problem only with picker.

Comment: Well, no. Binding Mode=TwoWay just tells the binding engine that it goes from source to target and from target to source, i.e if the property changes on View then it will propagate to ViewModel and vice versa. It does not raise the OnPropertyChanged for you. Your ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Umar3x, sorry, not Xamarin Forms, for this im using fody.propertychanged and freshmvvm. https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: Ow okay, I was missing a lot of information.

Comment: @Umar3x, its okay) Do you have any ideas? Actually binding works well, for everything except picker)

Comment: Yes I think you can try to bind SelectedIndex property of the picker and set it in your ViewModel. Your binding is working I think, prob is picker behavior. Setting the SelectedIndex should do what you expect.

Comment: @Umar3x, okay, i added property in xaml BindingContextChanged, added property to CheckListValue - index. Now each CheckListValue have index from 0 to 2 and in code behide setting SelectedIndex to SelectedItem.Index. Thank you)

Comment: Happy you found out how to solve your prob with SelectedIndex. You can up the comment if you'd like :)

Comment: @Umar3x, yes, sure. But i can't find how to do it) You can put it as answer and i will mark it)